# return false não funciona TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, script

Estou fazendo um código com TypeScript e eu faço a verificação se um campo tem menos de 9 dígitos, se ele tiver menos de 9, não deve prosseguir o submit, mas por algum motivo está prosseguindo.

```
<form method="post">
  Nome: <input type="text" id="nome"/>
  <button type="submit" id="enter">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Meu código em TypeScript está assim:

```
document.getElementById("enter").addEventListener("click", function () {
  if ((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("nome")).value.length < 9) {
    (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("tet")).innerHTML = "O Campo \"Nome\" deve conter 9 dígitos.";

    setTimeout(function () {
      (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("tet")).innerHTML = "";
    }, 5000);

    return false;
  }
});
```

e está dentro de um

```
window.onload = function () {}
```

e logo após ele, ainda dentro do `onload` tem um

```
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("form")).addEventListener("submit", function () {
});
```

ainda dentro do `window.onload`.

Oque estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Só pra descargo de consciência: você tem um elemento com o id `tet` na tela, né?

Comment: tenho sim kkk @LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que acontece aí  é que a submissão do formulário está sendo disparada no momento que você clica no botão.

Para que isso não aconteça é possível usar o método `preventDefault()` e depois disparar o *submit* manualmente.

Note que se existirem outros formulários na página será necessário especificar qual form deve ser submetido.

Veja um exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("enter").addEventListener("click", function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); // Previne que o submit seja disparado

    const nomeEl = document.getElementById("nome");
    
    if (nomeEl.value.length >= 9) {
        document.querySelector('form').submit(); // Faz o submit
    }
    else {        
        console.log("O Campo \"Nome\" deve conter 9 dígitos.");
    }
});
```

```html
<form method="post">
  Nome: <input type="text" id="nome"/>
  <button type="submit" id="enter">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Acho que seria bom notar também que está sendo feito um cast em `tet` para `HTMLInputElement`, e logo depois o `innerHTML` desse input é alterado. Mas inputs não possuem HTML interno, é bem possível que o @Samuel esteja fazendo cast de todos os elementos para `HTMLInputElement`, o que não apenas é desnecessário, mas também torna o código sujeito a erros.

Comment: Então cara, esse código me ajuda um pouco. O que acontece é que eu nao faço apenas o submit, no `(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("form")).addEventListener("submit", function () {
});` eu executo outras ações.

Comment: E o que tem? Só de adicionar o preventDefault já evita o submit automático.

Comment: Certo, consegui dar um jeito através do  seu exemplo. Obrigado @LINQ